# Maintain relation between duplicate and non-duplicate elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's consider I have a dataframe like:

```
+------------+
|    ColA    |
+------------+
| 1234567890 |
| 1234509870 |
| 1234589670 |
| 1234576890 |
| 3456789000 |
| 3456787970 |
+------------+
```

Requirement: All the elements with exact match of first 5 characters should be treated as 1, and only single element should be marked as non-duplicate with other duplicate with their selected element in another column.

I am already able to find out what are duplicate element by separating out first 5 elements in another column using below step:

```
df['ColA_5'] = df['ColA'].str[:5]
```

and then marking duplicates

```
df['Colc'] = df.duplicated(subset=['colA_5'],
                    keep='first').map({True:'non-dup', False:'dup'})
```

Thus, how do I create below mentioned dataframe using above dataframe.

```
+----------------------------+
|     ColA         ColB      |
+----------------------------+
| 1234567890   non-duplicate |
| 1234509870   1234567890    |
| 1234589670   1234567890    |
| 1234576890   1234567890    |
| 3456789000   non-duplicate |
| 3456787970   3456789000    |
+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform('first')` to broadcast all first values from each group back to their positions, and then just `mask` the actual first values to get the `non-duplicate` flag

```
g = df.groupby(df.ColA.astype(str).str[:5])
df['ColB'] = g.transform('first')\
              .ColA.astype(str)\
              .mask(df.index.isin(g.head(1).index), 
                                  'non-duplicate')
```

---

```
         ColA           ColB
0  1234567890  non-duplicate
1  1234509870     1234567890
2  1234589670     1234567890
3  1234576890     1234567890
4  3456789000  non-duplicate
5  3456787970     3456789000
```

Comment: I started getting "Error = Transform function invalid for data types" error for above solution. any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is by using [where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['ColB'] = df['ColA'].where(df['ColA'].str[:5].duplicated(), 'non-duplicate')
```

Comment: Simple. but doesn't link to what duplicate it originally is connected to